# Why is parallel dipole to electric field is stable equilbrium

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole

For a dipole making $0$ degree angle with field and for making $180$ degrees it is stable and unstable equilibrium respectively. Why?

Comment: Was typing "why?“ your only effort to answer yourself to this question?

Comment: You tagged this question as quantum-field-theory. It is just classical electromagnetism, not quantum field theory,

Comment: Do you know what the energy of an electric dipole in an electric field is?

Answer (score 1):

It is so because when the dipole is parallel or anti-parallel to the direction of electric field, there is no torque acting on the dipole but force is still exerted on it by the electric field. The reason it doesn't still move is that the net force on the dipole is zero i.e. $ \sum\vec F=0$.

Now coming to stable and unstable equilibrium,

When the dipole is aligned with the electric field $(0^0 ~~case)$ the potential energy of the dipole system will be lower than in any other configuration or what it would be in the $(180^0~~case)$ hence it is the most stable configuration and on the other hand when the dipole is anti-parallely aligned with the electric field the potential energy of the system will be higher than in any other configuration hence it's the least stable configuration.

What makes these two cases special is that these two configurations are the only possible ones when the net force on the dipole system is zero.

Moreover in stable equilibrium, the electric field  tries to rip apart the dipole configuration while in the unstable equilibrium situation, the field tries to compress the system. The potential energy change in both these actions are negligibly small for an ideal dipole.

The only important thing to consider is the potential energy of the electric field-dipole configuration and not the potential energy of the charges due to the increased or decreased separation  between them caused by the uniform field.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same case as for the mechanical analogy with a pendulum with the low and high vertical position.

The former position is in stable equilibrium, with the energy minimum.

The latter position is in unstable equilibrium,  with maximal energy, but without external cause to start deviating from the position to either direction.